# A value is required for bind parameter

Tags: mysql, sql, bind

sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) A value is required for bind parameter for `test2`.

```
INSERT INTO dashboard 
(source, test, test2) 
VALUES (%s, %s, %s)]
[parameters: [{'source': 'new_user', 'test': None, 'test2': None}]
```

> `test2` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL

However, my `test2` is there? Can anyone let me know that where the bug is? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

`test2': None` This is a fake one!! I do miss a placeholder for `test2`. Then we need to add it into the code! Bug fixed!